# Set focus on a react-bootstrap.Input field using refs.x.getDOMNode.focus

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The JSX:

```js
var Button = require("react-bootstrap").Button;
var Input = require("react-bootstrap").Input;
var MyClass = React.createClass({
        onclick: function () {
           this.refs.email.getDOMNode().focus();
           console.log('DOM element', this.refs.email.getDOMNode());
        }
        render: function () {
          return (
             <div>
                <Button onClick={this.onlick}>Login</Button>
                <Input ref='email' type='email' />
             </div>
            );
        },
    });
```

Notes:

1. The input field is a `react-bootstrap.Input` class.
2. The getDOMNode().focus() concept is from [Facebook react docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

When the button onclick handler runs, the email input field should be getting the focus, but it's not happening. I found that the react-bootstrap Input field class is rendering the real DOM input field inside a wrapping div. This is the output of the console.log:

```html
<div class="form-group" data-reactid=".1awy8d4e9kw.1.3.$=1$3:0.0.0.1.0">
  <input class="form-control" type="email" data-reactid=".1awy8d4e9kw.1.3.$=1$3:0.0.0.1.0.1:$input">
</div>
```

So looks like the input isn't getting the focus because the focus is applied on the wrapping div, which rejects it (I use `document.activeElement` in the console to check).

Question is, how to focus on the real `input` element?

Note:
A bit unrelated but React respects the `autoFocus` property. That's useful in case the focus is needed to be set immediately after rendering. Still, it's not a substitute for the programmatic way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `getInputDOMNode()` instead of `getDOMNode()`.

Comment: It is important to note that if using React 0.13 you should write `React.findDOMNode()` and after React 0.14 you should use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`.

Answer (score 9):

in render

```
<FormControl
  type='text'
  ref={(c)=>this.formControlRef=c}
  />
```

in event handler

```
someHandler() {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.formControlRef).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `findDOMNode` is no longer the suggested method and may be deprecated by Facebook, you should use the `autoFocus` property (which is provided by the React framework, not react-bootstrap). This is a cross-browser polyfill for the HTML `autofocus` attribute.

```
<FormControl
  autoFocus
  ...
/>
```

Sources:

1. [Focusing to the FormControl](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2153#issuecomment-240411831)
2. [Support needed for focusing inputs in modals?](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/192)

Answer (score 3):

FormControl provides `inputRef` attribute

try it,

```
<FormControl inputRef={ref => { this.input = ref; }} />
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/

Comment: This page is no longer found

Answer (score 0):

or you may use vanilla javascript and select the element and set focus

```
document.getElementById("myInput").focus()
```